# Not sure on method name of block code

Tags: ios, objective-c, queue, dispatch

I want to create a method which run's a user's provided block of code, making use of dispatch groups, and has the implementation as follows:

```
dispatch_group_enter(self.group);
block(^ {
    dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
    if (completion) {
        completion();
    }
});

dispatch_group_wait(self.group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

I'm not sure how to write the name of this method, however.

It'd be something similar to:

```
- (void)performBlock:(void(^)())block;
```

But then remember that the block provided has to have its own callback for completion.

The implementation would be something like this:

```
[object performBlock:^(void(^)() completion) {
    //Do stuff
    completion();
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have I misunderstood the question if I suggest?

```
- (void)performBlock:(void(^)())block completion:(void(^)())completion;
```

If I have not misunderstood I would recommend to add support for error handling

```
- (void)performBlock:(void(^)())block completion:(void(^)(NSError *err))completion;
```

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood. Updated with my idea of an implementation.

Comment: I admit that I am feeling confused. Is not your suggested implementation a compilation error?